# Efficient way to consolidate and sort list of tuples in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, tuples, big-o

I have a data class which mirrors the database model,

```
@dataclass
class Profile(object):
    uid: str
    interests: Tuple[str]
```

Each profile has its interests . The requirement is to have a method

```
get_sorted_interests(n)
```

which should return the `n` most interests among the profiles.

Below is my code,

```
import bisect

from collections import defaultdict
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Tuple

@dataclass
class Profile(object):
    uid: str
    interests: Tuple[str]
    following: Tuple[str]

def get_sorted_interests(n):
  """
  Get the most 'n' number of interests
  """
  return consolidate_and_sort_interests(n)


def get_profiles():
  # This method mocks a query with a very large
  # resultset.
  p1 = Profile('1', ('film', 'music'), ('3'))
  p2 = Profile('2', ('football', 'film'), ('1'))
  p3 = Profile('3', ('music', 'film'), ('1', '2'))
  yield p1
  yield p2
  yield p3

def consolidate_and_sort_interests(n):
  """
  Should return for eg: if n = 2
  [
    ('film', 3),
    ('music', 2)
  ]
  """
  d = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
  for p in get_profiles():
    for interest in p.interests:
      d[interest] += 1 
    
  sorted_list = []
  for key in d.keys():
      bisect.insort_right(sorted_list, (d[key], key))
  
  return sorted_list[-1:-(n+1):-1]
```

My main point of concern is the method `consolidate_and_sort_interests` . I need to have that optimised against runtime and space complexity.

Comment: This queston might be a better fit for [codereview.se]

Comment: To summarize, you need the top ```n``` results, correct?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur That is correct

Comment: @RampantSoze check this then: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-k-numbers-occurrences-given-array/